# 20.04: Command / Shortcut to toggle on-screen keyboard?

Tags: keyboard, touchscreen, execute-command, onscreen-keyboard

Currently I'm using Ubuntu 20.04 on my Microsoft Surface.

I want to have it so I can toggle the On-Screen keyboard via a command. I specifically mean this keyboard:

[image: on-screen keyboard]

Currently the only way to do it is through Settings, but I want to setup a keyboard shortcut to do this.

I don't want the keyboard popping up when I have my type cover plugged in and it's a bit of a hassle to go through Settings all the time when I plug it in.

This is the setting I'm referring to:

[image: Universal access settings]

Comment: Hi.. osk on screen keyboard cant be called on users wish.. turning screen keyboard switch on and off is possible based on users wish. do you want second one? it is possible..

Answer (score 3):

You can navigate to Settings → *Keyboard Shortcuts* and scroll down. You will find *Universal Access*. Under it there will be a *Turn on-screen keyboard on or off* option. See the following screenshot.

[image: Keyboard shortcuts]

After selecting the *Turn on-screen keyboard on or off* option, a dialogue box will appear asking you to set a shortcut key for the on-screen keyboard. Just press your preferred keys and it's done.

[image: shortcut dialogue box]